# Why pandastocsv does not write a proper value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to write my dataframe to csv, the only column that has a problem is shipping tracking number. In the df data look like "SHP5047828131", but after write into csv I got "SHP 5047828131.00" how can I figure it out. In setting I just only set index = False, encoding='utf-8'. What Should I add something?

Here's my code below

```py
import pandas as pd

List = ['SHP5047828131', 'SHP5047828678', 'SHP5047828625', 'SHP5047828926', 'SHP5047828767', 'SHP5047828679', 'SHP5047828952', '', 'SHP5047826824', 'SHP5047828384', 'SHP5047828856']
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(List))
print(df)

df.to_csv('/Users/sirilakkk./Desktop/test.csv', index = False, encoding='utf-8')
```

These two pic are the results first is from print directly and another is from csv file.

[df data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crBIU.png)
[csv data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X88uC.png)

Comment: Please show us a runnable example that we can try for ourselves.  What you're describing doesn't seem possible.  It's true that `"SHP5037828131"` is a legal currency value (Saint Helena pounds), but I don't think pandas aggressively tries to convert to currency values.

Comment: I just tried this and am unable to duplicate your problem.

Comment: I've already add the code example and the result pictures. Thanks for answering me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misdiagnosed your problem.  The file is being created correctly.  If you `cat test.csv` or bring up the file in an editor like vi, you'll see that it just fine.

The issue you have is with Excel, which interprets `SHP5047838131` as a currency value in Saint Helena Pounds.  It is Excel that is interpreting the data as currency.

If you wait to avoid that, you need to have quotes around the fields in the CSV.  You can have pandas do that by adding `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL`.

As a side note, you don't need `zip` if you only have one list.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv


List = ['SHP5047828131', 'SHP5047828678', 'SHP5047828625', 'SHP5047828926', 'SHP5047828767', 'SHP5047828679', 'SHP5047828952', '', 'SHP5047826824', 'SHP5047828384', 'SHP5047828856']
df = pd.DataFrame(List)
print(df)

df.to_csv('x.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```